# Queue multiple attacks with fleet works but landing army cannot queue multiple planet invasions

Tags: stellaris

The UI lets me select a landing battalion and queue (using the <kbd>shift</kbd> key) multiple planned landings on different planets ("let's me" as in: I can see the red path with each step show up).

However, in practice the army will only land on the last planet in the queue.

Whereas can queue up to 10 (or more?) solar systems to conquest with your naval fleet / attack / move commands and they will be diligently run through in the order that you gave.

Why is this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple explanations for why this is the case, the most obvious being "it hasn't been fixed yet." When the army lands, the queue gets interrupted because they change from being a transport ship into a planet garrison. Automatic re-embarking and following the queue just isn't coded in the game.

Likely this (lack of a) feature is a holdover from previous versions of the game. Assaulting any planet without bombardment used to be suicide unless you had overwhelming numbers so chain landings didn't happen as often. Since the need wasn't there, the ability to queue up transports for multiple planets wasn't a priority.

I agree that this is frustrating though and fixing transport ship queues would be a quality of life improvement.